# Understanding std::atomic memory barriers

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-barriers

I want understand how works memory barriers in C++.
For example, i am using std::atomic in that case:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>

int main()
{
    std::atomic<int> a;
    int n = load();//returns 1 or other value written by other thread
    a.store (n, std::memory_order_release);
}
```

Is that code above semantically equal to that below code?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
int main()
{
    std::atomic<int> a;
    int n = load();
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
    n = 100;//assume assignment is atomic
}
```

If i am right, can i be sure that behaviour is equal for all C++ functions which can accept memory barriers as argument?

Comment: Do you mean  at the second line of the main function, in the two exemples `int n = a.load(std::memory_order_acquire)` and at the second exemple, the fourth line: `a=100` ?

Comment: No, load function is not std::atomic load function. That is a user -implemented function which returns some data

Comment: The example seems muddled.  The first excerpt clearly stores a value into `a`.  But the second excerpt does not reference `a` at all, so why is it there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but it's equivalent to this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <atomic>
int main()
{
    std::atomic<int> a;
    int n = load();
    std::atomic_thread_fence(std::memory_order_release);
    a.store (12345, std::memory_order_relaxed);
    n=100;
}
```

(although the value is different than what you did up there). There **must** be an atomic store inside the fence. Check the conditions [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence) under "fence-fence synchronization" or "fence-atomic synchronization". Although you're not setting any constrains on storing `a`, it will be within the `memory_order_release`, and so will `n`. That's what a fence does.

Comment: As i understand you put that code a.store (12345, std::memory_order_relaxed); for provide atomic assignment. I just want know sequence of execution. Is barrier affect in the place as in my code?

Comment: @DarkRider The `memory_order_release` barrier *must* be before everything you want to have in order. On the other hand, the barrier of `memory_order_acquire` must be after everything you want to synchronize. That's why it's called a "fence". It's like you're putting synchronized stuff in a cage that starts with *release* and ends with *acquire*. Does that answer your question?

Comment: I just want know when i am calling a.store (n, std::memory_order_release); is that mean barrier is placed before calling all operations inside the store function? I can`t find appropriate source code for see that

Comment: @DarkRider When you're using a barrier, you don't have to `a.store (n, std::memory_order_release);`, because the barrier gives you that already. It's sufficient to do this: `a.store (n, std::memory_order_relaxed);`. But anyway, there must be some atomic store, whatever it's, otherwise the barrier won't work. Please read the page I provided: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_thread_fence